# How Hidden nested attribute of array in Laravel Model?

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

hi guys i use **Laravel** and **Mongo db** and i have profile object on User Model i have some attributes in User->profile like hashed password and ... then i should hidden them i try :

```
class User extends Eloquent implements Authenticatable
{
    use AuthenticatableTrait;
    use Notifiable;

    protected $hidden = [
        'mobile_password','profile.address','shaparak_info'
    ];
    protected $casts = [
//        'profile' => 'array'
    ];
}
```

but it dosen't work any idea ?

User Model Example :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("600fcd33808d665b6c7bd24a"),
    "mobile" : "+15125545454",
    "user_group_id" : "600c027069d6644ff9136870",
    "is_active" : "1",
    "is_confirm" : "0",
    "mobile_password" : {
        "password" : "$2y$10$71EKEgAKV6fQ61PvbbsFMeMKFnQ37aa4VbAc1h1TAM56TVCjylIFS",
        "send_date" : ISODate("2021-01-31T12:03:49.034Z")
    },
    "profile" : {
        "avatar" : "files/lw/fc/lwfcgy4fmxhy306o0yyd1mgfi.jpeg",
        "name" : "Me",
        "password" : "$2y$10$mRlUnTPgXkdH6FuMmGqPielu1.WCxBrxtll0Gecg.EQ1YgBtRjoD2",
        "nationalcode" : "123123123121",
        "father_name" : "Test",
        "email" : "email@gmail.com",
        "address" : "address",
        "nationalcartfile" : "files/sz/f8/szf8j41s7rvrvjapjpw9q3ojb.jpg",
        "otherfiles" : [ 
            "files/pv/mx/pvmxu9motjbk5fkcjyterprou.", 
            "files/lc/vi/lcviigrufkhlxeldqk32of4wl.jpeg", 
            "files/sy/jw/syjwzr20jyqbk7shbnmfkiq5b.jpg"
        ],
        "phone" : "0123456789"
    },
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2021-01-31T12:03:49.034Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2021-01-26T08:05:07.890Z")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the profile model and hidden the address

```php
class Profile extends Eloquent implements Authenticatable
{
    use AuthenticatableTrait;
    use Notifiable;

    protected $hidden = [
        'address'
    ];
...
```

If you want to hidden is you need to be in the right model

Comment: ummm ... i use Mongo DB for database and i use sub collections for this user Model

i add simple of my model u can check it